# Python IndexError: list index out of range. Can someone help me?

Tags: python

Can someone help me to solve my problem in this code?
CODE:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"}

url = "https://www.amazon.com/RUNMUS-Surround-Canceling-Compatible-Controller/dp/B07GRM747Y"

resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

s = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, features='lxml')

product_title = s.select("#productTitle")[0].get_text().strip()

print(product_title)
```

Comment: How do you know it found anything? You don’t check before taking the first result.

Comment: check `s.select("#productTitle")`, most likely length is zero

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

If you try to print what you get as response, you will not encounter related errors.

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"}

url = "https://www.amazon.com/RUNMUS-Surround-Canceling-Compatible-Controller/dp/B07GRM747Y"

resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(resp.content)
```

The output you are getting from this request:

```html
b'<!--\n        To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact api-services-support@amazon.com.\n        For information about migrating to our APIs refer to our Marketplace APIs...
```

The site you are sending requests is not allowing you to access content with provided headers. So your `s.select("#productTitle")` creates empty list therefore you are getting an index error.

Comment: Thanks dude, and can I put my request in an empty list to print it?

Comment: You can print it like the code snippet i provided `print(resp.content) `. You can mark answer as accepted, if it satisfy your question throughly. By doing that you can help others to find the solution faster.